# Is there any javascript-event which allows an action to be executed by the web-nav continually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a websocket using jQuery which is triggered continually after the load of the page. The idea, is to get information continually from the server and to display them into the web page without any refresh.

What kind of event is?

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Um... `setInterval` ?

Comment: Yes, HTML5 Websockets are designed exactly for this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ In other words, HTML5 websockets are so you *don't* have to constantly re-query the server.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, there is no limit about the number of executions. Does that function allows this fact ?

Comment: @user3289501 `setInterval` repeats given function at set intervals indefinitely until canceled via call to `clearInterval`

Comment: @user3289501 yes, setinterval can run indefinitely. However, if you are indeed using websockets, you don't need setInterval or setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval can be dangerous because of the timing of your http request/response.  Better to used chained setTimeouts, e.g.

```
var tick = function() {
   // do something here
   $('foo').toggle();

   setTimeout(tick, 1000); // wait 1 second and call again
};
tick();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an HTML5 Websocket is what you are looking for.

> The WebSocket specification defines an API establishing "socket" connections between a web browser and a server. In plain words: There is an persistent connection between the client and the server and both parties can start sending data at any time.

http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics

Comment: yeah, but when this is combined with SignalR of ASP.NET MVC, it needs an event to trigger an action.

Comment: Huh. Weird. Seems like .net isn't actually supporting it yet.

Comment: @user3289501 in that case. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: Maybe you need to reword the question as "how to get websockets working with .net"

Comment: @DA. i'm not a .net dev, but looking at that link makes me think it does support websockets.

Comment: @KevinB, Look at this function `$('#sendmessage').click(function () {...});` for each click on this button it will execute an action.

Comment: Right, but look at `chat.client.broadcastMessage = function`, it will get executed every time the server pushes an update to the client. No interval needed.

Comment: I haven't written .net code in about 6 years, so I am no expert these days, but a quick google seems to show that you can use Websockets with .net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617611/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-1 BTW, @user3289501 your example there is jQuery--so really has nothing to do with .net in that regard.

Comment: @KevinB, in my case, I'm trying to display each update on database in the end-user web-page. Do I need the part of code that I've mention? Because I'ven't written it and I can't send to the end-user the updates.

Comment: @DA., I'm not blaming you. Instead, you have helped me a lot and I'm grateful :))

Comment: if you can't send updates to the end user, then you aren't using websockets.